# If there are both componentWillReceiveProps and onSubmit, we want to give priority to onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I press a button on a Form, onSubmit works, but at the same time componentWillReceiveProps also works, and setState in componentWillReceiveProps takes precedence.

I would like to prioritize the setState of onSubmit instead of componentWillReceiveProps, what is the best way to do this?

If you know more about this, please let me know.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            title: nextProps.title,
        });
    }
```

```
onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let { title } = this.state
        this.setState({
            title: title,
        });
    }
```

Comment: Would you like both of them to be executed anyway? Just one before the other?

Comment: I want to disable componentWillReceiveProps when onSubmit is pressed.

Comment: You might be dealing with an anti-pattern. Refer to https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state "A common misconception is that getDerivedStateFromProps and componentWillReceiveProps are only called when props “change”. Perhaps, you should check `if (nextProps.title !== this.props.title)` before updating the state in your componentWillReceiveProps. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `Hooks`

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState()

const handleChangeTitle = e => {
  setTitle(e.target.value)
}

const handleSubmit = event => {
  alert(title)
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

And in `render()`

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    Title:
    <input
      type="text"
      value={title}
      onChange={handleChangeTitle}
    />
</form>
```

Don't forget to import it: `import React, { useState } from 'react'`

Comment: I'm using `onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });` to respond to more than just the title when entered.